# JavaScript что значит синтаксис такого вызова функции f()()

Tags: javascript

Как объявить в *javascript* функцию, чтобы ее можно было вызывать так: `f()()`, где `f` - имя функции?

Comment: Какова цель этого мероприятия?

Comment: нужно, чтобы функция f возвращала функцию.

Comment: В тестовом задании был такой вопрос

Comment: Для этого не нужны никакие извороты со скобками. [Например](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488937/).

Comment: @PinkTux, а где было про _извороты со скобками_? :)

Comment: Два раза скобки означают что оператор скобки применяется к f а потом к результату f(). В javascript оператор скобки применим только для функций, т.е f() должно вернуть ф-цию для которой применится второе ()

Answer (score 0):

Все разобралась, вот пример

```js
var f = function() {
  var func = function() {
    return 'result';
  }
  
  return func;
}

f()();
```

Выведет "result"

Comment: Спасибо Grundy за наводку)))

Answer (score 0):

```
var f = function() {
  return function() {
    return 'result';
  }
}
```