# Помогите разобраться с областью переменных функции

Tags: javascript

Объясните мне, почему в данном примере при первом вызове счетчика на выходе получаем `1`.
Ведь я так понял,что даже при первом вызове произойдет  `currentCount++` с областью переменных родителя, где `currentCount = 1`, таким образом вывелось `2`.

```js
function makeCounter() {
    var currentCount = 1;

    return function() { 
        return currentCount++;
    };
}

var counter = makeCounter(); 


console.log( counter() ); // 1
console.log( counter() ); // 2
console.log( counter() ); // 3


var counter2 = makeCounter();
console.log( counter2() ); // 1
```

Comment: @Grudny уверен, что вопрос про замыкания, а не про `i++/++i` ?

Comment: @teran, смотри [ответ Peter Olson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488941/186999) он как раз об этом

Comment: @teran, кроме того, в самом вопросе-дубликате почти дословно повторяется текущий: _Вопрос 1: почему при первом вызове функции переменная currentCount = 1, ведь возвращаемое функцией currentCount++, следовательно должно быть 2._

Comment: @Grundy и действительно :) надо было открыть вопрос ) я только заголовок прочитал :)